# Paypal Sandbox INTERNAL_SERVICE_ERROR

Tags: paypal-rest-sdk, paypal

I am a little confused at the moment i am trying to charge a credit card in sandbox mode on PayPal's Rest SDK.

When i attempt to take payment i am getting the following response:

> {
>     "status": 500,
>     "duration_time": 124,
>     "body": {
>         "message": "An internal service error occurred.",
>         "information_link": "https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/#INTERNAL_SERVICE_ERROR",
>         "name": "INTERNAL_SERVICE_ERROR",
>         "debug_id": "1d327d8a79044"
>     },
>     "additional_properties": {},
>     "header": {
>         "Content-Length": "209",
>         "Content-Language": "*",
>         "X-SLR-RETRY": "500",
>         "CORRELATION-ID": "1d327d8a79044",
>         "Date": "Thu, 14 Jul 2016 16:49:14 GMT",
>         "Connection": "close",
>         "Paypal-Debug-Id": "1d327d8a79044",
>         "PROXY_SERVER_INFO": "host\u003dslcsbplatformapiserv3001.slc.paypal.com;threadId\u003d200",
>         "Content-Type": "application/json"
>     }
>   }

I am unable to find anymore information on this,  I've searched various places and seen a few suggestions ive tried such as negative testing on/off and that made no difference at all.

Any help would be apreciated,

Comment: Tried using the same credentials here:
https://devtools-paypal.com/guide/pay_savedcard/php?interactive=ON&env=sandbox

Seems to give an error asking if credentials are correct, but the same creds are working fine for other API sandboxes (vault, payments etc).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding "INTERNAL_SERVICE_ERROR", in sandbox environment, the testing credit card in your API request is a generic one and there are lots of accounts attached to this credit card, when PayPal execute your API request, we need to load all the related accounts during transaction, so it caused time out error and internal service error, please try some rarely used card number, such as below:

```
VISA 16 digit
4916339731576481
4916037567876898
4024007171154213
4532782720397175
4556654893065114
4539432483175995
4716339122298416
4532325401406798
4539157680503828
4124138105007679
4485178251029161
4916231960500037
4058178241644969
```

Please have a try.

Comment: I dont quite understand why that isnt documented, I found a CC Generator and it worked fine, Thank you!